# stretch image's both sides but not center for uibutton

Tags: ios, uiimage, stretch, uiedgeinsets

I got an image,which is shorter than button's width, so I want to stretch the image's both sides to fit button's width but not stretch its center because there is text in center.  What should I do to achieve that? 
Appreciate your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Look for resizableImageWithCapInsets method of UIImage.

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

When 10 parameter is the margin of the text inside the image.

This creates a new UIImage that you can stretch.

Comment: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10) stretch the center, what I want is stretch two sides of image, but not center

Answer (score 0):

This can be achived by `resizableImageWithCapInsets`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:

or

you can also try

https://github.com/shiami/SWNinePatchImageFactory